# Insert records using date wise in table

Tags: mysql, procedure

Insert records based on date wise in table. like

```
'test1','test2','2017-12-10'
'test11','test22',2017-12-08'
'test12', 'test23', '2017-11-10'
```

latest date records will be on top. please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Rows have no order in relational databases, so the question is meaningless.

Comment: it will be very hectic to perform above thing, its of no use, but u can fetch in that way, or you can creat diffrent table for each day, like table_01,table_02 ..... table_20 , ..... table_31 etc.

Comment: Just to reiterate @Strawberry's very correct answer. The Order in which you insert data into a database table is 100% meaningless. That's not how a database works. You establish the order of records when selecting data out of your table for the result set being returned like `SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY your_date_column;`